Using a dual hose Portable A/C with a patio door or small exhaust port
I live in a 1BR apartment in the PNW that only has 1 window to the outside in the form of a sliding door out to a small balcony. I am constantly in a battle with keeping the temperature comfortable, as the inability to create any airflow makes it get stuffy very easily. I'm also on the 7th floor, so even as it gets cold outside it feels like warmth gets trapped in the apartment as it rises up from below and from the sun shining in through the balcony door. Here is a crude floorplan.
The apartment includes a small A/C vent port roughly 5" in diameter for connecting a portable A/C exhaust hose.
I initially purchased this LG portable A/C as its exhaust hose could fit in the port (after I screwed a plastic piece from Amazon with threading onto the wall over it). However this unit never worked great and started leaking within a month. When I returned it, I opted to replace it with this Toshiba unit that has 2 exhaust hoses. This unit works must better, but the 2 hoses mean I can no longer use the port in the wall.
This summer I set the unit up in the sliding door using weather stripping, the unit's window connector, and a piece of plexiglass. It worked okay, but the seal was never tight, it was susceptible to bumps, and it prevented me from ever opening the door and getting fresh air into the apartment.
My questions are:

Is there any way to connect the 2 hose output to the small vent I have, or would that ultimately be pushing too much air through too small a hole (if I could even find a compatible connector)?
If the above is impossible, is there any way to set the A/C up in my patio door that allows me to at least continue to open the door without the whole setup falling apart?



"is there any way to set the A/C up in my patio door that allows me to... continue to open the door...?

YES- one easy way I have seen is to install a sliding door pet-door panel. Where the pet door would normally be, you install a wood or foam (or other suitable material) panel with two holes that are cut to accommodate your AC exhaust hoses.
These pet-door panels are designed to allow continued use of the sliding door. The door latches to the panel instead of the original door jamb. Obviously, it won't open as wide as it did originally.


I have previoulsy directed in/out from a hosed AC into a sliding balcony door by using a pine board roughly matching the thickness of the door, and drilling the AC holes in the pine board. The board was about 1 inch thick, 1 foot wide and 7 feet long (to fit into the sliding door frame height- and thickness-wise). The holes were 5 inch in diam (determined by the diameter of the hose). To close the door, I would press it against the board, against D-gaskets on the board. The board was epoxy-coated b.c. this was in the UK (similar climate to the PNW). This rig held up for about 3 years, and I kept it in place during the winter as well. It was not totally water-tight though, as during heavy rain I could see small wet spots next to it. The sliding door functioned normally but could not be locked. The sound insulation was not as good as with the original door (no board).
For a water-tight solution in another apt, I have now set up an AC next to a swing-frame window, DIYed a double-pane polycarbonate (PC) window frame and inserted that in place of the existing window frame. I made 4 holes in it (2 for the AC and 2 for forced ventilation and an HRV exhaust). The PC is 5 mm thick which is a bit too soft, next time I would use 8 or 10 mm (0.2"-3/8"). This is water-tight, air-tight and sound-proof, but it was quie a bit of work. I realize that this solution may not apply to your case.
